# Unexpected results from passing int-value in multithreading, C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I am currently trying to learn about multi-threading in C. But I have got very unexpected results which have left me stumped. In this program, I am trying to fill up a matrix by using threads. I am creating 1024 threads, passing the i value into the function. Then I proceed to use it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define SIZE 1024

static double a[SIZE][SIZE];
static double b[SIZE][SIZE];
static double c[SIZE][SIZE];

void*
init_matrix(void* msg)
{
        int  j;
        int num = *((int*) msg);
        printf("%d\n", num);

        for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            a[num][j] = drand48();
            b[num][j] = drand48();
        }

        pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        //Init threads
        pthread_t p_initThreads[SIZE];

        int i,j;
        for(i = 0; i< SIZE; i++)                                                                                                                          
        {
                pthread_create(&p_initThreads[i], NULL, init_matrix, (void*)&i);
        }
        for(j = 0; j<SIZE; j++)
        {
                pthread_join(p_initThreads[j], NULL);
        }
}
```

Expected results from the prinf would be; 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10. With the possible
result of it being inorder due to of it being in threads. But the reults on my computer is this;

```
1-2-2-4-5-7-24-25-25-25-25-25-25-25-25-25-25-25-25-25-25-25-25-25-25-26-35-36-36-37-37-37-37-37-37-37-37-38-39-40
```

By commentating out;

```
for (j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            a[num][j] = drand48();
            b[num][j] = drand48();
        }
```

I get the result that I want. Why is that? It should not do anything to num!

Comment: All your threads' `msg` pointer point to the same variable, which you're modifying in `main()` while you're creating threads.  If the threads don't start right away and get past the `int num = *((int*) msg);` line before the next loop pass in `main()`, `num` won't get the value you expect -- and several threads might end up with the same (probably wrong) value.

Comment: You must ensure that no thread accesses an object while another thread is, or might be, modifying it. (Unless that object is of a type that specifically allows this.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the address of `i` as the input parameter of the thread. If you were passing the value of `i`, you would get 1-2-3-4-5-... . But when you pass the address, it is entirely possible that before  the `printf` line is executed, the main thread already incremented `i`. And `printf` displays the current value of `i`, not the value it had at the moment of thread creation.

Comment: You're totally correct. Buuuuut.. is it then even possible to do what Im trying to do? (by some typecast magic?) Or do I have to create a seperate array as a buffer? And then pass the addresses in that array?

Comment: For the purpose of just `printf`ing the value use `(void*)i` instead of `(void*)&i` and `int num = (int)msg;` for the assignment to `num`.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a [**race condition**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) with multiple threads accessing the same memory location (variable `i`) since you are passing the address of `i` to all threads.

What you really wanted to do was pass the *value* of `i`. Call the `pthread_create()` with:

```
pthread_create(&p_initThreads[i], NULL, init_matrix, (void*)i);
```

and read the value as:

```
int num = (int) msg;
```

instead of : `int num = *((int*) msg);`

You should also check if `pthread_create()` returns non-zero for failures. If that's the case, you are not going to get expected results.